# require module error in a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I've been trying to understand how to set up Stripe for my app but am having problems with the implementation of the module. Normally when using a module i would require it in the top of the file to be able to use it but when i do it in the paymentCtrl file it doesn't work and i get the two errors below: where am i supposed to declare it for me to be able to use it? Well as you see i'm quite new to this and would like to understand how to structure this so that the payments work.

errors:

> require is not defined
>       at paymentCtrl.js:1

and

> Failed to instantiate module paymentController due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'paymentController' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

paymentCtrl:

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_....');

angular.module('paymentController', [])


.controller('paymentCtrl', function($scope) {


});
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('userApp', ['appRoutes', 'userControllers', 'userServices', 'ngAnimate', 'mainController', 'authServices', 'managementController', 'paymentController'])

.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptors');
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `require` inside Angular application? I think you should do it on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's [Node.js library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) is meant to be used in server-side code. You should not embed it in client-side code, as doing so would reveal your secret API key.

In your client-side code, you can use [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) to collect and tokenize payment information.